# Laplace transform of an arbitrary function multiplied by a power law

Tags: laplace-transform, brownian-motion

In fractional Brownian motion, the Fokker-Planck equation is given by,

$$
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = 2D_{2H}Ht^{2H-1}\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
$$

I wish to take the Laplace transform of this equation in time-domain, but I am stuck with the product of two functions on the RHS, which is
$$
\mathscr{L}\big\{t^{2H-1}p(x,t)\big\}
$$

Any thoughts on how to write this as a Laplace transform of $p(x,t)$, what kind of functions can be adopted to calculate this Laplace transform (in terms of Fox functions or Mittag-Leffler functions etc.)

Comment: if $2H-1$ is an integer then $$\mathcal L (t^{2H-1} p)(s) = \left(-\frac{d}{ds}\right)^{2H-1}\mathcal L p(s)$$

Comment: It is not, but that is an interesting idea, may be I can use fractional derivatives